# Html table scraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to a table from SEC filling 10-K, I think it is going allright except the part where pandas converting it to dataframes as I am new to data frames so I think making mistake in indexing, Please help me on this as I am getting fallowing error "IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2"

I am using this programming

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1022344/000155837017000934/spg-20161231x10k.htm#Item8FinancialStatementsandSupplementary'
r = requests.get(url)
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,2), index = [0])
row_marker = 0
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    column_marker = 0
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    for column in columns:
        new_table.iat[row_marker,column_marker] = column.get_text()
        column_marker += 1

new_table
```

If dataframe issue isn't resolvable than please suggest any other substitute like writing data to csv/excel also any sugesstion for extracting mutiple table at once will be really helpful

Comment: `pandas` can already read html tables. have you tried taking a look at [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html)?

Comment: Thanks MattR for looking into it, I've tried the link you provided but that is far complex for a new user like me, so can you please write a few line for sample to enhance my understanding.

Comment: Sentdex from [Python Programming](https://pythonprogramming.net) has a great tutorial on `Pandas` and does a much better job than I ever could. [Here Is a link](https://pythonprogramming.net/dataset-data-analysis-python-pandas-tutorial/) that talks about reading HTML tables. Hopefully this will help you!